# Tailwind, Price comparison bar, inner div center while not changing other divs

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Currently I am working on something similar to this
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GJSS.png)

Goal is to have the bg-blue-500 (2nd div) that is inside the bg-gray-100 (first div), be exactly in the center, and the dashed lines to be on the outer parts of where the bg-blue-500, but also  the ability to have the span that holds the price of $249.00 be independent in the concept that if I want to make the content bigger it does not negatively affect the dashed line by moving it.

This is the current code

```
 <!--High / Low -->
          <div
            class="
              flex
              h-3
              my-8
              mr-8
              bg-gray-100
              border
              dark:bg-gray-700
              rounded-md
            "
          >
            <span class="bg-blue-500 bg-opacity-70  w-4/6 ml-10">
              <div class="grid grid-cols-2 text-xs">
                <div class="place-self-start flex flex-col">
                  <span
                    class="
                      border-dashed border-2 border-gray-300
                      pt-10
                      mt-2.5
                      w-1
                      self-center
                    "
                  ></span>
                  <span>$249.99</span>
                </div>
                <div class="place-self-end flex flex-col">
                  <span
                    class="
                      border-dashed border-2 border-gray-300
                      pt-10
                      mt-2.5
                      w-1
                      self-center
                    "
                  ></span>
                  <span class="border rounded p-5">$249.99</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </span>
          </div>
          <!--High / Low-->
```

Working example of the code above https://play.tailwindcss.com/d4BkNiESRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider applying `justify-content: center` to the top-level `<div>` to center the `.bg-blue-500`. To have the dashes aligned to the ends of the blue bar, apply `transform: translateX()` with `50%` to move it ½ of its width. Subtract ½ of the dash's `width` to have the edges aligned well.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div
  class="
    flex
    justify-center
    h-3
    my-8
    mr-8
    bg-gray-100
    border
    dark:bg-gray-700
    rounded-md
  "
>
  <span class="bg-blue-500 bg-opacity-70  w-4/6 ml-10">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 text-xs">
      <div class="place-self-start flex flex-col -translate-x-[calc(50%-(theme(spacing.1)/2))]">
        <span
          class="
            border-dashed border-2 border-gray-300
            pt-10
            mt-2.5
            w-1
            self-center
          "
        ></span>
        <span>$249.99</span>
      </div>
      <div class="place-self-end flex flex-col translate-x-[calc(50%-(theme(spacing.1)/2))]">
        <span
          class="
            border-dashed border-2 border-gray-300
            pt-10
            mt-2.5
            w-1
            self-center
          "
        ></span>
        <span class="border rounded p-5">$249.99</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```